# Error getting function from imported custom module in google collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a .py file loaded into google collab called dataset.py

This is the code i use to import this file with sharable link into google collab

```
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
dataset = drive.CreateFile({"id": *************})   # "your_module_file_id" is the part after "id=" in the shareable link
dataset.GetContentFile("dataset.py")          # Save the .py module file to Colab VM
from dataset import *
```

This code works and i can see dataset.py under the content folder in google collab

This is the function in the module dataset

```
def getData():
  transform_test = transforms.Compose(
      [transforms.ToTensor(),
      transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010))])
  transform_train = transforms.Compose([
      transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
      transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(), transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.10, contrast=0.1, saturation=0.10, hue=0.1),
      transforms.RandomRotation((-10.0, 10.0)), transforms.ToTensor(),
      transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010)),
  ])
  trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                          download=True, transform=transform_train)
  trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size= 128,
                                            shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

  testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                        download=True, transform=transform_test)
  testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=100,
                                          shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

  classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
            'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')
  return trainloader, testloader, classes
```

Now when i try to call this function in my google collab notebook as so

```
# getting the data
trainloader, testloader, classes = dataset.getData()
```

I get the folllowing error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-7598c0c8a079> in <module>()
     14 
     15 # getting the data
---> 16 trainloader, testloader, classes = dataset.getData()
     17 
     18 # Utilize GPU if available

AttributeError: 'GoogleDriveFile' object has no attribute 'getData'
```

Why am i getting this error

*Edit *

As suggested i tried

getData() directly . I got this error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b7ecc14896ac> in <module>()
----> 1 getData()

NameError: name 'getData' is not defined
```

Infact when i try to list the functions in the module using
print(dir(dataset))

The function is not listed i get some random stuff like

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `from dataset import *` which means you have directly imported all the functions in the module and can be used as they are.

Hence on the line 16, where you are getting error in your code, try replacing `dataset.getData()` with `getData()` only.

Had it been `import dataset`, the rest of the code would have worked fine.

Comment: I tried this as well. It did not help . The error i am getting now isNameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b7ecc14896ac> in <module>()
----> 1 getData()

NameError: name 'getData' is not defined this .